# Cant store encrypted Integer in Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laragon, rc4-cipher

I am Developing a website using Laravel that accept Online payment with Credit card and this must be encrypted before storing into the database
I am Using RC4 Encryption to encrypt an integer then store it in my database
it throwing an error cause after encryption it looks like that
r ���`�q�
so weird symbols and logos
it cannot be stored as my database collation is utf16 general_ci
I used something else but it didn't work
[This Error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYNko.png)

Comment: Have you look into Laravel's encryption logic? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption. That being said, even encrypting Credit Card information is a bad idea; use an external provider as suggested in the answer below. You do not want to be held liable if CC information is stolen from your application due to bad security implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted data is generally binary data, and the characters you show in your question suggest that's the case in your application.

A good solution to your problem is to use [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to convert your encrypted binary data to text before putting it into MySQL, and [base64_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to get back the binary data after you read it from MySQL.

**Warning: RC4 encryption is not secure.** It's been cracked for almost a decade.  If you use it to store sensitive credit card data, it is very likely that cybercriminals will steal that data. Your customers won't like that.

If you want to handle credit card data, your best bet is to use a payment service provider like stripe.com, paypal, or one of many others. You don't want credit card numbers, even encrypted ones, stored in your database.